# Is there a difference between the terms TestRPC and Testnet?

Tags: testrpc, testnets

From what I understand, a testnet is just a local (or private) blockchain for developers to experiment on, and TestRPC is/was a specific implementation of a testnet for the Ethereum blockchain?

(I say 'was' because it appears [Truffle absorbed TestRPC](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#looking-for-testrpc))

Answer (score 2):

Testnet is a real network for test purpose similar to the mainnet but with worthless Ethers.

TestRpc or ganache is a blockchain simulator which runs 100% **locally** which is much much faster than a any other deployment environment making it ideal for testing and development.